# Python List to Dictionary with Key Value

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am working in python for an authentication purpose. I need to retrieve the groups from the LDAP . The response i am getting is in the form of List . But i needed it in the form of Dictionary where Key should the "cn" value and Value should be the "uid".

How to do it .

```
 [
        [
            ('ou=mathematicians,
            dc=example,
            dc=com',
            {
                'objectClass': [
                    'groupOfUniqueNames',
                    'top'
                ],
                'ou': [
                    'mathematicians'
                ],
                'uniqueMember': [
                    'uid=euclid,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com',
                    'uid=riemann,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com',
                    'uid=euler,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com',
                    'uid=gauss,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com',
                    'uid=test,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com'
                ],
                'cn': [
                    'Mathematicians'
                ]
            })
        ],
        [
            ('ou=scientists,
            dc=example,
            dc=com',
            {
                'objectClass': [
                    'groupOfUniqueNames',
                    'top'
                ],
                'ou': [
                    'scientists'
                ],
                'uniqueMember': [
                    'uid=einstein,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com',
                    'uid=galieleo,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com',
                    'uid=tesla,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com',
                    'uid=newton,
                    dc=example,
                    dc=com'
                ],
                'cn': [
                    'Scientists'
                ]
            })
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Could you post what the ideal format would be?

Comment: Dict :
{Scientist = einstein,galieleo,tesla,newton}{Mathematicians = euclid,gauss,test}
The key should be the Cn and value should be the UId . This is what expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a pretty simple case of string parsing. Python is pretty powerful in that regard. I would recommend looking into the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more advance processing. In your instance, it looks like a matter of just iterating and flattening- so something like this:

```
import re

def flatten_LDAP(data):
    response = {}

    # Iterate through each item
    for dirty_el in data:

        # Manually flatten. Not robust, but good enough
        cn = dirty_el[0][1]['cn'][0]

        # Get users in list comprehension
        users = [
            # Split user from the string
            re.split(r'=|,',member)[1] 

            # Iterate from flattened 'uniqueMember'
            for member in dirty_el[0][1]['uniqueMember']
        ]

        # Add to dictionary
        response[cn] = users

    # Return
    return response
```

Should do the trick

I'm sure you could get a lot more fancy and process this on a streaming layer from LDAP- but I'm sure this will suffice.